# Maintain consistent colors while changing geom_bar order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

I'm struggling to maintain color consistency across charts while ordering geom_bar() based on another value.

Desired:

- A & B colors remain consistent between charts
- Each plot has descending order of A & B

Actual:

- A & B swap colors between charts

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(x = c("A","B"), y = c(1,2), z = c(4,3))
# Y
dat %>% 
  mutate(x = fct_reorder(x, y,`.desc` = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

```r
# Z
dat %>% 
  mutate(x = fct_reorder(x, z,`.desc` = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = z, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can maintain consistency of colours by setting the limits of a colour/fill scale. e.g. `+  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("A", "B"))`.

Comment: Or `scale_fill_manual(values=c("B" = "green", "A" = "red"))`. Not recommended for colorblind audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach ended up working for me:

```
dat %>% 
arrange(desc(z)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(x, desc(z)), y = z, fill = x)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```